# How can I make a video playing with video.js keep playing in the background on iOS?

Tags: javascript, video, video.js

On my website I have videos that play with video.js. When using the site through Safari on iOS, if I background Safari or lock my phone, the video pauses and I need to find the media controls and press the play button for the video to keep playing in the background. I have seen other websites using video.js where videos are able to keep playing automatically in the background.

How can I make my videos keep playing in the background on iOS?

This is my `<video>` element (jsx). I have tried different combinations of `playsinline`, `autoplay`, and `preload="auto"`.

```
      <video
        class="video-js"
        ref={(el) => void (videoRef = el)}
        playsinline
        autoplay
      />
```

And here is my code to setup up video.js, I have not been able to identity any parameters which change the behavior of playback when backgrounding my website:

```
    const player = videojs(
      videoRef,
      {
        controls: true,
        preload: 'auto',
        sources, // Array of `m3u8` URLs
        playbackRates: [1, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 2],
        html5: {
          hls: {
            overrideNative: false,
          },
          nativeVideoTracks: true,
          nativeAudioTracks: true,
          nativeTextTracks: true,
        },
      },
      async () => {
        try {
          await player.play();
        } catch (e) {
          // The play method is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied permission.
          console.warn('Could not automatically play video', e);
        }
      },
    );
```

I have had some success with the following code:

```
document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function() {
  if (document.visibilityState === 'hidden') {
    video.play();
  }
});
```

This works, however, it also plays paused videos when the page is backgrounded. Tracking the `pause` event doesn't work because `pause` is fired whenever the page is backgrounded and not just on user pauses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to work:

```
    let userPaused = false;

    player.on('pause', () => {
      userPaused = Boolean(player.userActive());
    });

    player.on('playing', () => {
      userPaused = false;
    });

    document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function () {
      if (document.visibilityState === 'hidden' && !userPaused) {
        try {
          player.play();
        } catch (e) {
          console.warn('Cannot play video while page is hidden.', e);
        }
      }
    });
```

In my testing this accurately tracks if the user has paused the video vs some other event, and keeps the video playing in the background when the user backgrounds the page.